# distribute output through FIFO

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, fifo

I'm trying to distribute very long make output using following method

```
mkfifo myfifo 
make 2>&1 | tee myfifo | grep -E "errors|warnings" myfifo > errors.log | cat myfifo
```

Idea is that subset of output should be copied to log files, while whole output would be redirected to stdout of console.

It seem to work at first, but suddenly stops and stays frozen until i press Ctrl-Z.

A use of process substitution

```
make 2>&1 | tee >(grep -E "errors|warnings" > errors.log)
```

is not possible, because shell compiled with  default strict POSIX compliance.

platform - ubuntu-flavored distro. shell bash 4.2 (and only one available)

Comment: tee is outputting to a pipe (in addition to that fifo), but grep is never reading from it, so after awhile the pipe fills up and the writes from tee will block. You also have a cat that's not reading from a pipe, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. But I think what you want to do can be done, in a modern shell, with just `make 2>&1 | tee >(grep -E "errors|warnings" > errors.log)`.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Thank you. I followed only source i had based literrally on analog of system V, Linux is a "obscure" OS here due to literature and language barrier. so proving queue as file doesnt work as reading it? there is proper content in errors.log and i suspected that something like is happening. i need output  to TWO different logs AND to console though

Comment: @Mark Plotnick syntax error near unexpected token (. That doesn't work in bash 4.2

Comment: @Mark Plotnik no luck, quick check on that error suggested that it requires non-posix feature, bash runs as if with --posix flag

Comment: That explains it - process substitution won't work with strictly-conforming POSIX shells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57624/discussion-between-swift-and-mark-plotnick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That

```
make 2>&1 | tee myfifo | grep -E "errors|warnings" myfifo > errors.log | cat myfifo
          P1           P2                                              P3
```

command makes little sense. It starts those 4 commands concurrently with pipes in between:

- `make 2>&1`: stdout and stderr goes to P1
- `tee myfifo`: stdin from P1, stdout to P2. So `tee` writes the output to both `myfifo` and P2.
- `grep -E "errors|warnings" myfifo > errors.log`: stdin from P2 but you're passing a filename (`myfifo`) to `grep`, so `grep` won't read from its stdin. stdout goes to `errors.log`, nothing writes to P3
- `cat myfifo`: stdin from P3 but again as `cat` is given a filename, it reads it instead. So both `grep` and `cat` read from `myfifo` concurrently.

Since nothing reads from P2, `tee` will hang when P2 is full. Also `cat` will not display the portions of `myfifo` that have been read by `grep`.

```
make 2>&1 | tee myfifo | grep -e errors -e warnings > errors.log | cat myfifo
```

is closer to what you meant I think. Again P3 is not used, but we're using the `|` to start `cat` concurrently and wait for it.

Or you could do:

```
make 2>&1 | tee myfifo & grep -e errors -e warnings > errors.log
wait
```

If you need more `grep`s, you need more fifos:

```
make 2>&1 | tee fifo2grep1 fifo2grep2 &
grep errors fifo2grep1 > errors.log &
grep warnings fifo2grep2 > warnings.log
wait
```

On systems that support `/dev/fd/x`, you can also do:

```
make 2>&1 | { tee /dev/fd/3 | grep -e errors -e warnings 3>&-; } 3>&1
```

(that's typically what process substitution does in shells that support it).

With 2 `grep`s, that becomes:

```
make 2>&1 |
 {
   {
     tee /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 |
       grep errors > errors.log 3>&- 4>&-
   } 4>&1 |
     grep warnings > warnings.log 3>&-
 } 3>&1
```

Comment: Marvelous explanation. so if i need two different greps, i reiterate, using additional fd/n ?

Comment: @Swift, see edit

Comment: @Swift, yes sorry. Typo fixed now. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

After `grep -E "errors|warnings" myfifo > errors.log` the pipe no longer contains data. So the next command `cat myfifo` which read from the pipe will be blocked.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to print all messages to stdout, and redirect all error and warning messages to `errors.log`. So if you want to use pipe, use two:

```
 mkfifo pipe1 pipe2 
 make 2>&1 | tee pipe1 pipe2 | grep -E "errors|warnings" pipe1 > errors.log | cat pipe2
```